# How to search for any unicode symbol in a character string?

Tags: unicode, latex, ibm-doors

I've got an existing DOORS module which happens to have some rich text entries; these entries have some symbols in them such as 'curly' quotes.  I'm trying to upgrade a DXL macro which exports a LaTeX source file, and the problem is that these high-number symbols are not considered "standard UTF-8" by TexMaker's import function (and in any case probably won't be processed by Xelatex or other converters) .  I can't simply use the `UnicodeString` functions in DXL because those break the rest of the rich text, and apparently the character identifier `charOf(decimal_number_code)` only works over the basic set of characters, i.e. less than some numeric code value.  For example,  `charOf(8217)` should create a right-curly single quote, but when I tried code along the lines of

```
if (charOf(8217) == one_char)
```

I never get a match.  I did copy the curly quote from the DOORS module and verified via an online unicode analyzer that it was definitely Unicode decimal value 8217 .

So, what am I missing here?  I just want to be able to detect any symbol character, identify it correctly, and then replace it with ,e.g., `\textquoteright`  in the output stream.

My overall setup works for lower-count chars,  since this works:
( `c` is a single character pulled from a string)

```
    thedeg = charOf(176)
 if( thedeg == c )
        {
           temp += "$\\degree$"
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some help from DXL coding experts over at [IBM forums](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=1f9a8785-4f9a-434a-8240-c03a8b2ad1c7#repliesPg=0).

Quoting the important stuff (there's some useful code snippets there as well):

> Hey, you are right it seems intOf(char) and charOf(int) both do some
>   modulo 256 and therefore cut anything above that off. Try:

```
int i=8217;
 char c = addr_(i);
 print c;
```

Which then allows comparison of `c` with any input char.

Comment: Is there reverse function for it? I mean is there intOf() equivalent which does not do module 256?

Comment: Found it: char c = addr_(10625)